# Using Xcode 6.1 I can't drag and drop objects to Main.storyboard

Tags: xcode6

I am facing the following problem: When creating a new project in Xcode (Single View) I am not able to drag and drop objects from the library to the view. They "jump" back immediately to the lib.
What am I doing wrong? Can anybody help me?

Thanks a lot!
Chris